# Adding factor variable into a continuous multi-plot

Tags: r, plot

[image]

I have created this plot using code

```
plot(kitedata_2[, 3:6])
```

I'd like to add a factor to the plot, that can be differentiated using different colour points. I.e. to separate each measurement into male and female values.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try adding something like `col=ifelse(kitedata_2$sex=="female","red","blue")` to your call to plot. Or providing a reproducible example.

Comment: You could always use the panel option in the pairs function.

Answer (score 0):

The `ifelse` function is your friend in situations like this.

```
sample_data <- mtcars[,1:4]
colors <- ifelse(mtcars$am, "blue", "pink")
plot(sample_data, col = colors)
```

[image]

For situations where you want three or more colors, the `cases` function from the `memisc` package will perform a similar function:

```
library(memisc)
sample_data <- mtcars[,c(1, 3, 5)]
colors <- cases(
  mtcars$cyl == 4 -> "red",
  mtcars$cyl == 6 -> "blue",
  mtcars$cyl == 8 -> "green"
)
plot(sample_data, col = colors)
```

[image]

However, your most powerful and flexible tool for this would be to use the `ggplot2` package. Here is one way of accomplishing coloring based on a variable using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x = mpg, y = drat, col = factor(cyl), geom = "point", data = mtcars)
```

[image]

Learning how to use the `ggplot2` package would be a valuable long-term investment.